# Shell script loop call functions from another file, getting command not found. Syntax mistake?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this file which is executing functions from other files:

```
#!/bin/sh

for ABC in dir.d/*; do

   . $ABC

   echo -n "Checking for $ABC..."

   if ${ABC}_find; then
      echo "yes"
      ${ABC}_download
      ${ABC}_cleanup
      break
   else
      echo "no"
      ${ABC}_cleanup
   fi
done
```

and the files in the dir.d directory are
filename: one

```
#!/bin/sh

one_find() {
echo "one found"
}

one_download() {
echo "one downloaded"
}

one_cleanup() {
echo "one removed"
}
```

same for file with a filename two

```
#!/bin/sh

two_find() {
echo "two found"
}

two_download() {
echo "two downloaded"
}

two_cleanup() {
echo "two removed"
}
```

I am getting the following output:

Checking for dir.d/one..../myfile.sh: 13: ./myfile.sh: dir.d/one_find: not found
no
./myfile.sh: 20: ./myfile.sh: dir.d/one_cleanup: not found

I tried to google, that didn't solve my problem. I am a newbie at shell, and this is my first question in SO. Some more details:

1.I cannot rename the files, the filenames have to match function name starting (before _)

2.I need to import in the loop itself because there may be hundreds of files in dir.d just like one and two

EDIT:
These files are a part of a project. I am using git, and I am coding partially in windows using notepad++ and partially in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) using nano/gedit. I am copypasting some code to/from windows and Linux (My Ubuntu is a Virtual Machine running in another window in VMware). Does it affect the code anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you add `dir.d` two times.

It must be

```
for ABC in dir.d/*; do
   . $ABC
done
```

and you write it

```
for ABC in dir.d/*; do
   . dir.d/$ABC
done
```

which is obviously wrong.

**Update**

Also, it is wrong to do

```
if ${ABC}_find; then
```

because you have `dir.d/one` in `ABC`.
You must cut `dir.d` off.

Another option: first `cd` to `$ABC` and then iterate through its content.
In this case $ABC will keep the sole names of files.

```
cd dir.d
for ABC in *
do
  if ${ABC}_find
  then
  ...
  fi
done
```

**Update 2**

Just to be 100% sure I've just checked your script with my suggestions:

```
for abc in dir.d/*; do
 . $abc
 ABC=${abc#*/}

 echo -n "Checking for $ABC..."

 if ${ABC%*/}_find; then
  echo "yes"
  ${ABC}_download
  ${ABC}_cleanup
  break
 else
  echo "no"
  ${ABC}_cleanup
 fi
done
```

Result of its execution:

```
$ sh 1.sh 
Checking for one...one found
yes
one downloaded
one removed
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. I had tried removing dir.d. I am getting the error when using . $ABC as well. I apologize for pasting old code, Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I'll edit it.

Comment: It still says one_find not found. I tried both keeping the . $ABC and removing . $ABC, yet getting the same error. I have also done chmod 0777 to each file one,two,.. yet getting the same error..

Comment: OMG! It worked!! Thank you so much @IgorChubin!! I really appreciate for taking the time to help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd fix it this way:

```
#!/bin/sh

for FILE in dir.d/*; do
   . "$FILE"

   ABC=${FILE##*/}

   echo -n "Checking for $ABC..."

   if "${ABC}_find"; then
      echo "yes"
      "${ABC}_download"
      "${ABC}_cleanup"
      break
   else
      echo "no"
      "${ABC}_cleanup"
   fi
done
```

Also, it would be a good idea to give your subscripts the .sh extension:

```
for FILE in dir.d/*.sh; do
   . "$FILE"

   ABC=${FILE##*/}; ABC=${ABC%.sh}
```

When you get into larger modular projects, you may also consider framework solutions like [Shell Script Loader](http://loader.sourceforge.net/). Also check conservative concept script for Bash 4.0+ [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/loader/code/ci/base/tree/custom/loader-include-prototype-bash-4.0+.bash).